# Call objects from a list which reproduces object names

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qcheckbox

I'm creating an application which has many checkBoxes. Every 4 checkBoxes are inside of a `groupBox_n` (n=36) and these groupBoxes are then inside of another groupBox.

Each checkBox is named following a certain rule which is very convenient for me. I want to have access to each of them, but I don't want to type their name every time. So I though about reproducing their names in a list, so that I could iterate over the list and have control, depending on their names.

But when I try to connect a button calling a string from my list, I'm not able to do that. Here I reproduced an example with a QLineEdit.

Is it possible to do something like that?

Calling `findChildren`does not help me, because then I don't know what is the position of my checkBox in my application, or "who is who" there. Calling by ObjectName is also not possible, is it?

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))

        self.My_lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.My_lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("My_lineEdit"))

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        MyStrinng = 'My_lineEdit'
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), self.Mystring.clear)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Like this, `PyQt` does not recognize my string as the object's name. I also tried to make a `PyQt` string with `QCore.QString('My_lineEdit')`, but `QString` is not available for my version [(you can see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510890/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-qtstring)

with this I can reproduce the names of all my checkboxes.

```
names = []

for x in range(0, 6):
    for y in range(0, 6):
        for z in range(1, 5):
            Names = 's'+str(x)+str(y)+'0'+str(z)
            names.append(Names)
print(names)
```

Comment: Do you want to get every checkbox for your objectName?

Comment: It's important that which box is which when I get a list.
I didn't know I could specify the name in the search. Thanks!
Do you think I can in somehow compare it with my list of names, the one I created? Something like `for name in Mylist: myList = parentWidget.findChild(QPushButton, "name")`

Comment: Yes, if you can, but explain yourself better. According to your question you have a pattern in the names, you could place a valid example for what you want.

Comment: Example: `another_list = [parentWidget.findChild(QPushButton, name) for name in Mylist]`

Comment: Just put the necessary code, retranslateUi and everything that code needs is unnecessary.

Comment: Did my answer work for you? Any questions?

Comment: I put the names, those are all my checkBoxes. I Think now I can access the ones I want, by doing as you said. But I need a bit of time to try it :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find an object by its object, the simplest option is to use [`findChild()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild):

> **T QObject::findChild(const QString &name = QString(),
>   Qt::FindChildOptions options = Qt::FindChildrenRecursively) const**
>
> Returns the child of this object that can be cast into type T and that
>   is called name, or 0 if there is no such object. Omitting the name
>   argument causes all object names to be matched. The search is
>   performed recursively, unless options specifies the option
>   FindDirectChildrenOnly.
>
> If there is more than one child matching the search, the most direct
>   ancestor is returned. If there are several direct ancestors, it is
>   undefined which one will be returned. In that case, findChildren()
>   should be used.
>
> This example returns a child QPushButton of parentWidget named
>   "button1", even if the button isn't a direct child of the parent:
>
> ```
> QPushButton *button = parentWidget->findChild<QPushButton *>("button1");
> ```

The example in C++ that is in the documentation would be translated to python of the following form:

```
button = parentWidget.findChild(QPushButton, "button1")
```

In your case:

```
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        ...
        # change self.lineEdit to self.My_lineEdit
        #Form is the parent of My_lineEdit                     
        self.My_lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form) 
        self.My_lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("My_lineEdit"))

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        ...

        le = Form.findChild(QtGui.QLineEdit, "My_lineEdit")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(le.clear)
```